# OpenXml Creating a Spreadsheet with DataValidations

Tags: openxml

I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml version 2.5 for .Net 4.5.2.  I have created a WorkBook with two Sheets. The second sheet provides lookup data for data validations in the first sheet.  When I finish the second sheet, I do the following to connect them:

```
    var sheet = workbookpart.WorksheetParts.First().Worksheet;

        var extLst = new WorksheetExtensionList();
        var ext = new WorksheetExtension();

        var dataValidations = new DataValidations();

        dataValidations.Count = 2;

        var jobSplit1dataValidation = new DataValidation
        {
            Type = DataValidationValues.List,
            AllowBlank = true,
            SequenceOfReferences =
                new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "K2:K990" },
            Formula1 = new Formula1("JobSplitLookup!$A$2:$A$6")
        };

        var jobSplit2dataValidation = new DataValidation
        {
            Type = DataValidationValues.List,
            AllowBlank = true,
            SequenceOfReferences =
                new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "L2:L990" },
            Formula1 = new Formula1("JobSplitLookup!$B$2:$B$5")
        };

        dataValidations.Append(jobSplit1dataValidation, jobSplit2dataValidation);

        ext.Append(dataValidations);

        extLst.Append(ext);

        sheet.Append(extLst);
```

When I build the spreadsheet and look at the parts, I see these data validations in the first sheet, and I see the data in the second sheet.  Everything looks like it is in place.  However, in the first sheet, the data validations are not active when I select an applicable cell.

To compare, I have added data validations manually and inspected the xml.  It is different, in that there are some namespaces applied to the ext and dataValidations elements, and the formula1 node has "f" and "sqref" child elements, whereas the OpenXml generates the sqref as an attribute of the dataValidation, and formula1's inner text is the reference to the range.

Must be (at least) one thing I've just overlooked.  Does it jump out at you?

Comment: Maybe the `dataValidations` node already exists. Did you try something like: `var dvs = worksheet.GetFirstChild<DataValidations>();` and then if `(dvs != null)
        {
            dvs.Count = dvs.Count + 1;
            dvs.Append(dataValidation);
        }
        else
        {
            DataValidations newDVs = new DataValidations();
            newDVs.Append(dataValidation);
            newDVs.Count = 1;
            worksheet.Append(newDVs);
        }`

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I have verified that there are no pre-existing dataValidations.